# Check if time already occupied using sql query

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently developing s reservation system for meeting rooms, I'm having a trouble checking the time range if it is occupied. Example 9:00 - 11:00 is already occupied, if the other user will set or input 9:30 - 10:30 alert must show that time is already occupied and the reservation will not save to database.

this query is what I've tried, but it only works when the inputted time-in and out has same value..

```
SELECT * FROM `reservation`
    WHERE time_in = '$time_in' AND time_out = '$time_out' AND day = '$Fday' AND meeting_table = '$selected_radio'
```

$time_in,$time_out,$Fday is the value in selection box that the user set their time. And the $selected_radio, is the value of selected radio for their desired area to reserve.

my table 'reservation' looks like this :

```
id | emp_id | emp_name | month | day | year | meeting_table | time_in | time_out 
1  | 23345  | name     | 09    | 03  | 2019 | area 1        | 7:00    | 9:00
```

Comment: could you add some sample data off the reservation table

Comment: @skybunk I've editted it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL: Vacant / occupied rooms as now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686182/mysql-vacant-occupied-rooms-as-now)

Comment: You can simply combine all datetime fields into two: datetime_in and datetime_out. It is easier that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use BETWEEN:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    reservation
WHERE
    (
        time_in BETWEEN ('$time_in' AND '$time_out') OR
        time_out BETWEEN ('$time_in' AND '$time_out') OR
        '$time_in' BETWEEN (time_in AND time_out) OR
        '$time_out' BETWEEN (time_in AND time_out)
    ) AND 
    day = '$Fday' AND 
    meeting_table = '$selected_radio'
```

This query will meet situations like:
**9:00 - 11:00** - existing reservation

**08:00 - 09:30** - ocuppied
**10:30 - 12:00** - ocuppied
**10:30 - 12:00** - ocuppied
**07:30 - 08:30** - free
**11:30 - 12:30** - free
**07:00 - 12:00** - occupied

I believe you should keep your time slots like **8:00 - 8:59**. Making it **8:00 - 9:00** will give you a false 'occupied' if somebody tries to schedule the slot **9:00 - 10:00**, as the `time_in` will be at same time as the `time_out` of the previous reservation.

**Important!!!** 
The way it is, your code is open to SQL Injection attacks! I recommend using PDO to fix it. [PHP PDO Prepared Statements Tutorial to Prevent SQL Injection](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection) is a good tutorial on how to use it.

**EDIT:**
Added two more conditions to WHERE clause, to cover the situations when somebody tries to schedule a time slot with `time_in` and `time_out` between the start and end times of an existing reservation.

E.g.:
**09:00 - 11:00** - existing reservation

**10:00 - 10:30** - occupied

Comment: gives me an error string(282) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR time_out BETWEEN ('' AND '')) AND day = '' AND meeting_table' at line 2"

Comment: @Gelxxxx you are running the query without passing any value to the variables. that's why you get this error. But this query is fine for what you need

Comment: This is broken. If there is a reservation for 9:00 - 11:00 then it fails for 10:00 - 10:30.

Comment: @SalmanA You are right! Thanks for catching that! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query. `CAST` to `datetime` first before working with `time`.

```
    SELECT * FROM `reservation`       
    WHERE 
     time_in >= cast('$time_in' as datetime) and time_out <= cast('$time_out' as datetime) 
       AND day = '$Fday' AND meeting_table = '$selected_radio'
```